# When to programmatically create custom Django permissions?

Tags: python, django, permissions

The permission/authentication documentation for Django 1.4 provides the following snippet for creating custom permissions programmatically:

**Edit:** (I would like to employ this for permissions that are *not* necessarily linked to a specific model class, but more general permissions that span multiple types.)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='myapp', model='BlogPost')
permission = Permission.objects.create(codename='can_publish',
                                       name='Can Publish Posts',
                                       content_type=content_type)
```

[Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#programmatically-creating-permissions)

My question is *where* this code should be placed. Obviously these should only be created once, but I don't want to have to do it in the shell. It seems like this should be stored in a file somewhere. (For documentation sake.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it is enough to just add the needed permissions to the corresponding model class using the `permissions` meta attribute.

This is from the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#custom-permissions):

```
class Task(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("view_task", "Can see available tasks"),
            ("change_task_status", "Can change the status of tasks"),
            ("close_task", "Can remove a task by setting its status as closed"),
        )
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have clarified - this is for global permissions, or permissions that are not linked to a specific model class.

Comment: I see. What if you store it in a fixture?

Comment: I'm very new to both Python and Django, but a quick Google search indicates that fixtures might be a good solution. I'll poke around, thanks!